# Mobile hamburger menu action doesn't work at first page load on Magento 2.2

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, hamburger-menu

I'm using **Magento 2.2.x** with a free theme

> http://www.venustheme.com/theme/ves-fasony-free-magento2-theme/

And my problem is that the hamburger menu action, and also the cart action, doesn't work as it should. The menu doesn't work properly, and the cart, sends you to the demo page, instead of opening the cart popup.
I think there is some javascript not loading, cause after a while of clicking around, and browsing some pages, it works, any idea?